# Sort a column automatically when an entry is added/deleted and directly create/delete a related row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, insert, addition

I'm trying to create a google sheet that sorts new entries automatically in the "Name" column (see image1).

I found the sorting script online, and it works as needed regarding the "Name" sorting.
However, if I typed a new name in the "Name" column (for example "N"), it sorts it automatically and creates a new row for "S1", but not for "S2" (See image2); likewise, if I deleted a name (for example "K"), it shifts up the data below it and moves the related cells of "Name" and "S1" to the bottom in a new row, but it doesn't do that for "S2" (See image3).
So the data is messed up whenever a new entry or a delete is made.

How to make the code creates a new row for S1 and S2 whenever a name is added, and how to make it automatically deletes the whole row if a name is deleted.

Here is my script:

```js
function autoSort(e){
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const column = e.range.getColumn()  ;
  const ss = e.source;
  const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName();

  if(!(currentSheetName === "Scores" && column === 2 && row >=2)) return

  const range = currentSheet.getRange(2,2, currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,2);

  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
 }

 function onEdit(e){
  autoSort(e)
 }
```

[image1][image]

[image2][image]

[image3][image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last parameter of this line from

```
const range = currentSheet.getRange(2,2, currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,2);
```

to

```
const range = currentSheet.getRange(2,2, currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,3);
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)